# Which is better? Using an array of primitive type of an array of corresponding class

Tags: java, arrays, generics, real-time, circular-buffer

I am trying to write a class using so that I can implement a circular buffer of any type of data. There are two options that I see right now. First, I create a class using generics where the generic type would be used to determine the type of array that I want to initialise for the  circular buffer. Here, I would have to use the array of the `class`. Second, I create an abstract base class defining the common components and extend this class for the implementation of different types of buffers that I want to use. For instance, if I want to create an instance of circular buffer of type `int`, I can create it in the implementation of my child `class`. Here, I can use the `primitive datatypes` to create the arrays. My application is real-time and would access these buffers in real-time. So, I would want to know which is an efficient solution.

Comment: The performance impact of boxing and unboxing class instances of primitives may be quite large, and it's not certain if it can be reliably optimized by the JIT to eliminate boxing in all cases.

Comment: If you want it to be generic for *any* type of data, you have to use boxed primitives, since you can't use primitives in generics (you *can* use primitive arrays, though).

Comment: So, would it be better to create my own class of boxed `int` type rather than using the `Java.Lang.Integer`? Also, what would be the performance points over using the `primitive datatypes`?

Comment: What benefit do you think your version of `java.lang.Integer` would have over the "real" version?

Comment: Well java.lang.Integer is a bigger object and extends java.lang.Number, so I guess boxing and unboxing it would be a bit more costly than if I create my own class. No?

Answer (score 2):

The second approach will perform better because unboxing and (in particular) autoboxing have a performance hit.

The collections will also have a considerably smaller memory footprint too, so that's another benefit.

These reasons are why collection frameworks like GS Collections (now Eclipse Collections I believe) and Guava include primitive implementations of their collections.

The downside is that you will have more code to write up-front, and you won't have a single class that can be used in all circumstances.

Comment: Since I do not have to implement this for a lot of datatypes in my system, I think I will go ahead using the `primitive types`.